# php project deployment problem

Tags: php

i have done onw project in php. It works on my windows pc. I use xampp on my windows machine.But when i devlopy same on my linux machine it shows me some blank pages.
Some pages are completely blank.some are half blank.

whats the problem?

Comment: ...I might have accepted some answers before asking yet another question...

Answer (score 2):

Those blank pages could be because there is an error that is not displayed -- will be hard to guess what, though, so here are a couple of pointers :

Did you check if there is anything useful in your Apache's log files *(something like `/var/log/apache/error.log`, or close to that, generally)*.

You can also enable [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and/or configure [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting), to get more informations -- or have them displayed on screen, which might be a bit easier, as long as you are developping and your application is not deployed to the production server.

This can be done in the php.ini file, if you can modify it, with something like this :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

Or it can also be done directly in your code, at the beginning of it, with something like this :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

To enable [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for all kinf of errors, and display those errors.

You might also want to install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) on your development box, to get nice [stacktraces](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace) when an error / exception occurs -- just don't install it on a production server !

Of course, on your production machine, you probably don't want to display errors ; so that will have to be configured depending on your environment ;-)